# equation for measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, \Omega, \mu)$ be a measure space, $p : X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$ measurable and $\mu_{p} : \Omega \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}, A \mapsto \int_{A} p\,d\mu$ a measure on $\Omega$.

I need to prove that $\int_{X} f\,d\mu_{p} = \int_{X} f \cdot p\,d\mu$

for all measurable functions $f : X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$.

Hint is to first show this for simple functions and then use the monotone convergence theorem, but I don't know how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what a simple function is? What do you get if you replace the $f$ in $\int_X f d\mu_p$ by a simple function?

Answer (score 1):

The standard route here is indicator functions, simple functions, measurable functions.

Suppose $f=1_A$, where $A$ is measurable. Then $\int f d \mu_p = \int 1_A d \mu_p = \mu_p (A) = \int_A p d \mu  = \int 1_A p d \mu = \int f p d \mu$.

Now suppose $f$ is simple, that is $f = \sum_k \alpha_k 1_{A_k}$. Then linearity of the integral gives the desired result.

Finally, if $f$ is measurable, there is a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ such that $f_n(x) \uparrow f(x)$ for all $x$. In this case we can take the $f_n(x) \ge 0$. Note that we also have $f_n(x) p(x) \uparrow f(x) p(x)$. Then apply the monotone convergence theorem twice to get the desired result.